# iOS (Today) Widget - launch app by tapping on app icon

Tags: ios, swift

Most widgets (Apple and 3rd party) will take you to the application if you tap on the icon in the title/header of the widget.

I looked, but I can't find the documentation for that option.

- HIG
- Extensions docs

Even Apple's sample widget app does not include this functionality:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/notificationcenter/building_a_simple_widget_for_the_today_view

NOTE: this is not the same as enabling app launching in the wight's content area. That is documented the docs, and the sample app implements it, and I've tested it.

```
    /// - Tag: OpenMainApp
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Open the main app at the correct page for the day tapped in the widget.
        let weatherForecast = weatherForecastData[indexPath.row]
        if let appURL = URL(string: "weatherwidget://?daysFromNow=\(weatherForecast.daysFromNow)") {
            extensionContext?.open(appURL, completionHandler: nil)
        }
```

Comment: (due to the downvotes without commas, I added the Apple code in the sample app that works, but not for the UI element I described.) Yes, this lets you tap-to-the-app, and it is working Apple code. No, it is not the code path that I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## In general, the app icon in the title bar of the widget should launch (or foreground) the app when tapped.

The test results I had described before were in simulator. For some reason, it was not working for several days, then suddenly, it started working, including the sample app provided by Apple, mentioned above.

When checking all the apps on my phone IRL, I had noticed that some of them do not do this, including

- Favorites
- Siri
- Battery

My current interpretation is that these widgets are provided by the systems as extensions, but possibly not directly tied to a loaded app, hence, the app icon cannot take you back to a parent app.

(Right now, my apps don't seem to side-load, so I haven't been able to verify end-to-end, that is, I haven't taken one of the apps I have in Xcode, and push it to a real device to confirm the explanation).